# Another product in XML list gets deleted when I refresh the page after deleting one

Tags: php, xml, forms

When I click on delete link for a product, it deletes the product from my `XML` product list based on its associated id. But when I refresh the page after deleting a products, it deletes another product. Can you please help me what I am doing wrong here? Why is it deleting a product each time I refresh the page?

Thanks in advance for your suggestion.

This is the coidng that I have been working with:

```
<?php
   $products = simplexml_load_file('data/product.xml');

   if(isset($_GET['action'])){
       $products = simplexml_load_file('data/product.xml');
       $id = $_GET['id'];
       $index = 0;
       $i = 0;

       foreach ($products->product as $product){
           if($product['id']==$id){
               $index = $i;
               break;
           }
           $i++;
       }
       unset($products->product[$index]);
       file_put_contents('data/product.xml', $products->asXML());
   }

   ?>
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" broder="11">
   <tr>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Option</th>
   </tr>
   <?php foreach ($products->product as $product) { ?>
   <tr>
      <td><?php echo $product['id']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $product->name; ?></td>
      <td>
         <a href="index.php?action=delete&id=<?php echo $product['id']; ?>"
            onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')">Delete</a>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <?php } ?>
</table>
```

The XML file format is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<products>
    <product id="1">
        <name>Product 1</name>
    </product>
    <product id="2">
        <name>Product 2</name>
    </product>
    <product id="3">
        <name>Product 3</name>
    </product>
</products>
```

Comment: think you need to specify the item you deleting, not just action, for example a check for item $_GET['id'], not just $_GET['action']

Comment: Thanks, but even if I change it from `$_GET['action']` to `$_GET['id']`, it returns the same result of deleting another item after refreshing.  :(  @LeoTahk

Comment: update xml file format

Comment: Updated the xml @kranthi

Comment: updated ans try with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <?php
       $products = simplexml_load_file('data/product.xml');

       if(isset($_GET['action'])){
           $products = simplexml_load_file('data/product.xml');
           $id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : '';
           $name = isset($_GET['name']) ? $_GET['name'] : '';
           $index = 0;
           $i = 0;
          foreach ($products->product as $key=>$product){
             if($product['id']==$id && $product->name == trim($name)){
              unset($products->product[$i]);
              break;
            }
           $i++;
          }
           file_put_contents('data/product.xml', $products->asXML());
       }

       ?>
    <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" broder="11">
       <tr>
          <th>Id</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Option</th>
       </tr>
       <?php foreach ($products->product as $product) { ?>
       <tr>
          <td><?php echo $product['id']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $product->name; ?></td>
          <td>
             <a href="index.php?action=delete&id=<?php echo $product['id'].'&name='.$product->name; ?>"
                onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')">Delete</a>
          </td>
       </tr>
       <?php } ?>
    </table>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It was a great lesson. I really appreciate your effort. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try with below code

```
foreach ($products->product as $product){
       if($product['id']==$id){
           $index = $i;
           break;
       }
       $i++;
   }
   unset($products->product[$index]);

to 
   $i = 0;
  foreach ($products->product as $key=>$product){
       if($product['id']==$id){
          unset($products->product[$i]);
           break;
       }
        $i++;
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the delete function is not working now with this code. It doesn't delete any element.

Comment: Wow! This works fine. But only one issue here is that if two products (with different name) has same id, it again deletes the other one after refreshing. Is it happening because we are deleting a child based on their `id`? What might be the possible solution in this case other than giving each product an unique id? Thanks for your effort.  :)

Comment: 1. while deleting send product name also and add in if condition with id.                          2. add some other unique attribute to product like id

Comment: Can you please update the code for that scenario? That would be really helpful.

Comment: added one more ans check it